# Windows Phone: Is it possible to mix toast notification and scheduled alarm?

Tags: windows-phone-8, notifications, windows-phone-8.1, reminders

I'm new to Windows Phone development. I'm going to implement reminder App with following features:

1. Remind every day/week/month
2. When remind occurs display it in notifications list

And I've got problem with it:

1. Alarms / Remind API is pretty good for my task. But it doesn't
   create notification (I wanna see my remind in notifications list)
2. `ScheduledToastNotification` creates notification but it has too many schedule limitations

How to create correctly scheduled alarm + Toast notification?

Comment: Silverlight 8, 8.1 or Windows Runtime?

Comment: Silverlight 8.1 - RT doesn't support Alarms / Reminders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately when it comes to exact timed notifications, those are your only two options.

A possibility would be to use the regular Reminder and create the Notifications [silently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.suppresspopup.aspx) (without showing the toast popup). Won't be very reliable though.

If you can live with varying timings, you can try:

- You could check out [TimerTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.aspx) but it has a lot
  of limitations either.
- In Silverlight [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx) may work
  for you (max. every 30 Min)

Comment: TimeTrigger is not only RT - it works also in WP8.1 Silverligt.

Comment: `and create the Notifications silently` - can you explain it?

Comment: A notification has a suppress popup property that blocks the visual so it only shows up in the action center. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.suppresspopup.aspx